# Displaying circles for an array of datapoints in d3 and angular?

Tags: angular, d3.js

In my component.html file, I have a code snippet:

```
            <ng-container *ngFor="let datapoint of datapoints$ | async">
                    <svg:circle cx="datapoint?.x" cy="datapoint?.y" r="5" />
            </ng-container>
```

and the result is that the ui shows nothing, and the following error appears in the console:

```
Error: <circle> attribute cx: Expected length, "datapoint?.x"
```

`x` and `y` are both of type `Number`.

I've tried `parseInt` on the string because it looks like html is taking the value as a string and not actually looking for the `x` and `y` of the point, but it hasn't helped. Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe you want `[cx]="datapoint?.x"` , or even `[cx]="datapoint.x"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Now, I get a new problem - `core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property cx of [object SVGCircleElement] which has only a getter`. I'll start taking a look at it, but do you have any ideas...?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that setting `cx` to `[attr.cx]` works. This change is applied to `cy` as well.